# Is it haram to read fan fictions that mention sex to learn, how to do it but never use it except for the halal sex with my wife?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sex, husband-wife, family

Learning to please my wife. Please tell a modest answer with facts. I have scoured the internet for every halal site I can but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Salam brother

There are many books available on amazon and all

That teach you how to please your wife and yourself halal way

May Allah help you and keep you away from sins